# Multi-event tournament standings

Tags: mysql, group-by, ranking

I am trying to grab a participants rankings in a multi-event tournament.

I can do a ranking for a single event pretty easily. Is there a way to find ALL in one go?

```
Given input: "Bob"


Data example:               Desired output:

Name | Event | Score        Name | Event | Score | Rank
--------------------        ----------------------------
Bob      1     100          Bob      1     100      1    
Bob      2      75          Bob      2      75      3
Bob      3      80          Bob      3      80      2
Jill     2      90
Jill     3      60
Chris    1      70
Chris    2      50
Chris    3     100
Amy      1      85
Amy      2      95
Amy      3      65
```

The catch: I do not have access to the Rank()
function with my version of SQL, and updating is not possible in this scenario.

Clearly I could just do the score per event separately in a loop, 
but I'd like to try to do it all in one go.

Comment: is rank is just a serial number isn't it?

Comment: Its the participant's place in the event. Like 1st, 2nd, 3rd, etc.

Comment: @Strawberry: the values of `Score` for event 3 are {80,60,100,65}, making Bob 2nd.

Comment: A solution for pre-8 versions of MySQL... https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xcxcrdsBShWxr4Z8WTzJMS/1

Comment: Is it possible to make it track ties? As it is, if two people are first place, the one below is read as Rank 2.

Comment: @schwooples My answer also works with pre-8 MySQL versions and if two people are tied (e.g. for 1st) the next person will get the appropriate rank i.e. 3rd

Comment: See -  https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xcxcrdsBShWxr4Z8WTzJMS/2 - or something like that anyway. Remember, if addressing a comment to a specific individual, you need to include @individual - otherwise the individual might not see the message.

Comment: And, just for fun, here's another method... https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xcxcrdsBShWxr4Z8WTzJMS/3

Comment: @Strawberry Number 2 works very well! But now what if each person had multiple attempts at the event? Like "best of 3 (or N) attempts". So you would have a database of all the players various attempts. How would you filter out each players best attempts and rank them?

Comment: I think this is verging on the territory of 'an entirely different question', and thus beyond the scope of the comments section. I suggest you ask a fresh question, referencing this one.

Answer (score 1):

You can emulate a ranking function in MySQL using a self-join to values with a higher score in the same `Event`, and then counting the number of higher scores for each participant:

```
SELECT s1.Name, s1.Event, s1.Score, COUNT(s2.Name)+1 AS Rank
FROM scores s1
LEFT JOIN scores s2 ON s2.Event = s1.Event AND s2.Score > s1.Score
WHERE s1.Name = 'Bob'
GROUP BY s1.Name, s1.Event, s1.Score
ORDER BY s1.Name, s1.Event
```

Output:

```
Name    Event   Score   Rank
Bob     1       100     1
Bob     2       75      3
Bob     3       80      2
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/xcxcrdsBShWxr4Z8WTzJMS/0)