# Multi-event tournament standings (with arbitrary number of entries)

Tags: mysql, ranking

Suppose you have a a multi-event competition where competitors can attempt any event an arbitrary number of times. (weird, I know.)

How do pull out a desired player's best time for each event,
and assign it a placing? (1st 2nd 3rd...)

```
Data example:               Desired output:

Name | Event | Score        Name | Event | Score | Rank
--------------------        ----------------------------
Bob      1      50          Given input: "Bob"
Bob      1     100          Bob      1     100      1   
Bob      2      75          Bob      2      75      3
Bob      3      80          Bob      3      80      2
Bob      3      65      
                            Given input: "Jill"
Jill     2      75          Jill     2      90      1
Jill     2      90          Jill     3      60      3
Jill     3      60
                            Given input: "Chris"
Chris    1      70          Chris    1      70      2
Chris    2      50          Chris    2      85      2
Chris    2      85          Chris    3     100      1
Chris    3     100
```

This is a build up of my previous question: 
[Multi-event tournament standings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56215702/multi-event-tournament-standings)

I feel understand that problem much better (Thanks!), but I cannot bridge the gap to this version of the problem.

I have SQL 5.x so I cant use stuff like Rank(). This will also be crunching many thousands of scores.

Comment: It should be easy in MySQL 8.x. I don't know about 5.x, though. Which one do you have?

Comment: Why in Desired output players sorted "Bob", "Jill", "Chris". Is that sorting important?

Comment: @TheImpaler I have 5.x, that's why I'm struggling so much.

Comment: @MaksymMoskvychev I'd like it to return the scores of only the person that is entered.

Comment: Why is Chris' rank `2` for both events `1` and `2`?

Comment: @stickybit Because his best score in each event is the 2nd best overall in each event.

Comment: So, first thing: If you don't have a PRIMARY KEY, then you don't really have a table.

Answer (score 0):

Desired output can be acheaved with this query:

```
select
IF(event is NULL, CONCAT('Given input: "', name,'"'), name) as name,
IF(event is NULL, '', event) as event,
IF(event is NULL, '', max(score)) as score,
IF(event is NULL, '', (
  select count(s2.name) + 1
  from (
          select name, max(score) as score
          from scores es
          where es.event = s.event
          group by es.name
          order by score desc
        ) s2
  where s2.score > max(s.score)
)) as `rank`

from scores s
group by name, event with rollup
having name is not NULL
order by name, event;
```

And output (if run query in mysql cli):

```
+----------------------+-------+-------+------+
| name                 | event | score | rank |
+----------------------+-------+-------+------+
| Given input: "Bob"   |       |       |      |
| Bob                  | 1     | 100   | 1    |
| Bob                  | 2     | 75    | 3    |
| Bob                  | 3     | 80    | 2    |
| Given input: "Chris" |       |       |      |
| Chris                | 1     | 70    | 2    |
| Chris                | 2     | 85    | 2    |
| Chris                | 3     | 100   | 1    |
| Given input: "Jill"  |       |       |      |
| Jill                 | 2     | 90    | 1    |
| Jill                 | 3     | 60    | 3    |
+----------------------+-------+-------+------+
11 rows in set, 3 warnings (0.00 sec)
```

Should work on any Mysql 5.

Comment: I don't think you can use rollup like this in 5.

Comment: @Strawberry why not? It works perfectly in this case to create separation lines like "Given input: "Bob""

Comment: I think you've misunderstood the intent of the question.

Answer (score 0):

You can get the highest score per event by an aggregation by event taking the `max()`. To simulate a `dense_rank()` you can use a subquery counting the scores higher than or equal to the current score per event.

For a particular contestant (here Bob) that makes:

```
SELECT d1.name,
       d1.event,
       max(d1.score) score,
       (SELECT count(*)
               FROM (SELECT d2.event,
                            max(d2.score) score
                            FROM data d2
                            GROUP BY d2.event,
                                     d2.name) x1
               WHERE x1.score >= max(d1.score)
                     AND x1.event = d1.event) rank
       FROM data d1
       WHERE d1.name = 'Bob'
       GROUP BY d1.event
       ORDER BY d1.event;
```

And for all of them at once:

```
SELECT d1.name,
       d1.event,
       max(d1.score) score,
       (SELECT count(*)
               FROM (SELECT d2.event,
                            max(d2.score) score
                            FROM data d2
                            GROUP BY d2.event,
                                     d2.name) x1
               WHERE x1.score >= max(d1.score)
                     AND x1.event = d1.event) rank
       FROM data d1
       GROUP BY d1.name,
                d1.event
       ORDER BY d1.name,
                d1.event;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=663a1c015190ca06f0ad3ae41c96aa5f)

Answer (score 0):

E.g.:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS my_table;

CREATE TABLE my_table
(id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY
,name VARCHAR(12) NOT NULL
,event INT NOT NULL
,score INT NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO my_table (name,event,score) VALUES
('Bob'  ,1, 50),
('Bob'  ,1,100),
('Bob'  ,2, 75),
('Bob'  ,3, 80),
('Bob'  ,3, 65),
('Jill' ,2, 75),
('Jill' ,2, 90),
('Jill' ,3, 60),
('Chris',1, 70),
('Chris',2, 50),
('Chris',2, 85),
('Chris',3,100);

SELECT a.*
     , FIND_IN_SET(a.score,b.scores) my_rank
  FROM my_table a -- it's possible that this really needs to be a repeat of the subquery below, so
                  -- ( SELECT m.* FROM my_table m JOIN (SELECT name,event,MAX(score) score FROM my_table 
                  -- GROUP BY name, event) n ON n.name = m.name AND n.event = m.event AND n.score = m.score) AS a
  JOIN
     (
SELECT x.event
     , GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT x.score ORDER BY x.score DESC) scores
  FROM my_table x 
  JOIN 
     ( SELECT name
            , event
            , MAX(score) score 
         FROM my_table 
        GROUP  
           BY name
            , event
      ) y 
     ON y.name = x.name 
    AND y.event = x.event 
    AND y.score = x.score
  GROUP 
     BY x.event
     ) b
    ON b.event = a.event
 WHERE FIND_IN_SET(a.score,b.scores) >0;
+----+-------+-------+-------+------+
| id | name  | event | score | rank |
+----+-------+-------+-------+------+
|  2 | Bob   |     1 |   100 |    1 |
|  3 | Bob   |     2 |    75 |    3 |
|  4 | Bob   |     3 |    80 |    2 |
|  6 | Jill  |     2 |    75 |    3 |
|  7 | Jill  |     2 |    90 |    1 |
|  8 | Jill  |     3 |    60 |    3 |
|  9 | Chris |     1 |    70 |    2 |
| 11 | Chris |     2 |    85 |    2 |
| 12 | Chris |     3 |   100 |    1 |
+----+-------+-------+-------+------+
```

Comment: ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'rank
  FROM my_table a

Comment: @MaksymMoskvychev Yes - the request was specifically for older versions of mysql. Feel free to call 'rank' anything you like.

Comment: This is fantastic! But my guess is I'm hitting the limit of GROUP_CONCAT as its not returning all the necessary rankings.

Comment: @schwooples yes, that can happen. You can adjust that limit, but probably better to switch back to the @ variable solution or - best of all - upgrade!

Comment: I'm not qualified to say, but I imagine the topic is widely discussed

Comment: @Strawberry I bumped up GROUP_CONCAT size and it works now, but is this regular or dense ranking? There weird discrepancy.

Comment: I think that question is above my pay-grade